# Can't implement the shout cast server from the Programming Erlang book by Joe Armstrong

Tags: erlang

Is it just me or does the code for the shout cast server in the Joe Armstrong Programming Erlang book(2nd edition) Chapter 17(Programming with Sockets) not work at all. I was able to get a more recent version of the code from: http://media.pragprog.com/titles/jaerlang2/code/jaerlang2-code.zip    ... but still it doesn't work. Was wondering if anyone has implemented it successfully or if there is a github link to the correct working code. This has really impeded my learning of Erlang.

Many thanks.

Edit: 
I am very sorry for not putting more detail in the question. 
I didn't want to bother anyone with reading a long question if they have already read the book and implemented it successfully.

Here's what I did: I modified the mp3_manager.erl code a bit on line 14:

```
Files = lib_files_find:files("/Volumes/joe/piano_concertos", "*.mp3", true),
```

to

```
{ok, CurrDir} = file:get_cwd(),
Dir = CurrDir ++ "/shoutCast_Music",
{ok, Files} = file:list_dir(Dir),
```

When I run the mp3_manager.erl start1 function as directed the contents dumped to the mp3data file is:

```
[{"Careful Where You Stand - Coldplay.mp3",{error,enoent}},
 {"Parachutes - Coldplay.m4a",{error,enoent}},
 {"See You Soon - Coldplay.mp3",{error,enoent}},
 {"Shiver - Coldplay.mp3",{error,enoent}},
 {"Trouble - Coldplay.mp3",{error,enoent}},
 {"U.F.O. - Coldplay.mp3",{error,enoent}}].
```

I didn't think the server would work right with those errors.
I even tried to change the music files to have just id3 v 1 tags
with a music tags software I downloaded at: 
http://ftp.is.co.za/mirror/ftp.gnome.org/binaries/win32/easytag/2.2/easytag-2.2.5-setup.exe

I am using Erlang version 17.

Comment: Might be a syntax difference between current erlang and when the book was written.  What error(s) are you getting? compile time? run time?

Comment: generally, in this forum, the usage is to explain what you have done so far, and at least the error message you have got.

Comment: Programming Erlang 2nd Edition uses Erlang 17. Is that the version you are using?

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the example from the book but the {error,enoent} means the VM is trying to open a file which is not there.

I would print the full path to the file to ensure your file reference is correct. You can do that with io:fwrite("~p~n",[FilePath]).